# Partition of the vertices in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

In a graph $G$ such that for every set of $4$ vertices exists a triangle or exists an independent subset of three elements. Show that is possible partition the vertices of the graph in $2$ sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ induces a complete graph and $B$ is an independent subset.

I tried use induction over the number of vertices, the base case is easy but I can not finish it. Any help or hint will be welcome.

Comment: No need for induction. Let $G$ be a finite graph satisfying your hypothesis, i.e., $G$ does not have $K_2\cup K_2$ or $P_4$ or $C_4$ as an induced subgraph. Let $B$ be a maximum independent set of vertices. Show that the complement of $B$ induces a complete subgraph of $G$. Although this argument uses that $G$ is finite, the result also holds for infinite graphs by a compactness argument like the Erdős–De Bruijn theorem. More generally, $V(G)$ can be partitioned into a clique and an anticlique iff $G$ does not contain $K_2\cup K_2$ or $C_4$ or $C_5$ as an induced subgraph.

Comment: By the way, a graph whose vertex set is the union of a clique and an anticlique is called a *split graph*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a (finite) graph satisfying your hypothesis. If $E=\varnothing$ we can simply choose a vertex $a\in V$ and let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=V\setminus A$, so we may assume that $E\ne\varnothing$.

Let $B$ be a maximum independent set in $G$, and let $A=V\setminus B\ne\varnothing$. Note that each vertex in $A$ has at least one neighbor in $B$. I claim that $A$ induces a complete subgraph of $G$. Assume for a contradiction that there are two vertices $a_1,a_2\in A$ with $a_1\ne a_2$ and $a_1a_2\notin E$.

Case 1. We can choose two distinct elements $b_1,b_2\in B$ so that $b_1$ is a neighbor of $a_1$ and $b_2$ is a neighbor of $a_1$. Then $\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\}$ is a set of $4$ vertices which violates your hypothesis.

Case 2. There is an element $b\in B$ which is the only neighbor of $a_1$ and the only neighbor of $a_2$ in $B$. Then removing $b$ from $B$ and replacing it with $a_1$ and $a_2$ produces a larger independent set, contradicting the assumed maximality of $B$.